# How to use the Azure Gatekeeper design pattern?

Tags: c#, api, azure, design-patterns, cloud

I've found the following official documentation by MS. But I'm not sure how to implement this? 
[Gatekeeper Deisgn Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gatekeeper)

Do I have to create this pattern manually? or is it already available in Azure as a service which I can use? If so, how to make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern described in the link above is a generic pattern, use it as you see fit.  There is no "gatekeeper service" per-say in Azure, but there are several tools in the Azure toolbox that you can use to employ that pattern.  A couple of examples:

- [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/services/api-management/)
- [Azure Application Gateway](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/)

How you incorporate this pattern in your solution is ultimately up to you.  I'm sure there are other 3rd party solutions deployed from the marketplace.